# How can i download file from the internet in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, file, download

I don't know what the problem is...The compiler (Qt) runs program without errors, but the file is not downloaded...
Can you tell me please tell what is wrong?

I made by example "download", which is located in the qt folder. The only difference is that they have is a console, and I have windows application.

**mainwindow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H
#include <QtNetwork>
#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {

    class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

class DownloadManager: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    QNetworkAccessManager manager;
    QList<QNetworkReply *> currentDownloads;

public:
    DownloadManager();
    void doDownload(const QUrl &url);
    QString saveFileName(const QUrl &url);
    bool saveToDisk(const QString &filename, QIODevice *data);

public slots:
    void execute();
    void downloadFinished(QNetworkReply *reply);
};


#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QtNetwork>
#include <QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <QStringList>
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QFile>
#include <QFileInfo>
#include <QList>
#include <QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <QNetworkRequest>
#include <QNetworkReply>
#include <QStringList>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QUrl>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
#if defined(Q_WS_S60)
    w.showMaximized();
#else
    w.show();
#endif

    return a.exec();
}

DownloadManager::DownloadManager()
{
    connect(&manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),
            SLOT(downloadFinished(QNetworkReply*)));
}

void DownloadManager::doDownload(const QUrl &url)
{
    QNetworkRequest request(url);
    QNetworkReply *reply = manager.get(request);

    currentDownloads.append(reply);
}

QString DownloadManager::saveFileName(const QUrl &url)
{
    QString path = url.path();
    QString basename = QFileInfo(path).fileName();

    if (basename.isEmpty())
        basename = "download";

    if (QFile::exists(basename)) {
        // already exists, don't overwrite
        int i = 0;
        basename += '.';
        while (QFile::exists(basename + QString::number(i)))
            ++i;

        basename += QString::number(i);
    }

    return basename;
}

bool DownloadManager::saveToDisk(const QString &filename, QIODevice *data)
{
    QFile file(filename);
    if (!file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open %s for writing: %s\n",
                qPrintable(filename),
                qPrintable(file.errorString()));
        return false;
    }

    file.write(data->readAll());
    file.close();

    return true;
}

void DownloadManager::execute()
{
    QStringList args = QCoreApplication::instance()->arguments();
    args[0]="http://www.google.ru/images/srpr/logo3w.png";

QString arg=args[0];

        QUrl url = QUrl::fromEncoded(arg.toLocal8Bit());
        doDownload(url);

}

void DownloadManager::downloadFinished(QNetworkReply *reply)
{
    QUrl url = reply->url();
    if (reply->error()) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Download of %s failed: %s\n",
                url.toEncoded().constData(),
                qPrintable(reply->errorString()));
    } else {
        QString filename = saveFileName(url);
        if (saveToDisk(filename, reply))
            printf("Download of %s succeded (saved to %s)\n",
                   url.toEncoded().constData(), qPrintable(filename));
    }

    currentDownloads.removeAll(reply);
    reply->deleteLater();

    if (currentDownloads.isEmpty())
      //   all downloads finished
        QCoreApplication::instance()->quit();
}
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"


MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}


void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    DownloadManager manager;

    manager.execute();
    QTimer::singleShot(0, &manager, SLOT(execute()));
}
```

Comment: Try converting those `fprintf`s into message boxes or some other GUI thing; it may be showing errors but you can't see them because it's a GUI application rather than a console application.

Comment: -1 for lazily copying and pasting the whole code, instead of isolating the relevant parts.

Comment: OK, thanks. I added a QMessageBox, but it still nothing happens.
No any MessageBoxes does not show...

Comment: Try stepping through each function in a debugger. Put a breakpoint on the start of each function.

Comment: Thanks to all! It works if after that: QStringList args = QCoreApplication::instance()->arguments();
    args[0]="http://www.google.ru/images/srpr/logo3w.png";

QString arg=args[0];

        QUrl url = QUrl::fromEncoded(arg.toLocal8Bit());
        doDownload(url);                                                             after that lines i added: QMessageBox msgBox;
        msgBox.setText("Wait...");
        msgBox.exec();

Comment: But why is this so? I am interested.....

Comment: A good alternative to QMessageBox when debugging in Qt is qDebug().  It can be used like std::cout or printf.  And it shows up in the Application Output pane in Qt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is at that point of your code:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    DownloadManager manager;    
    manager.execute();
}
```

`QNetworkAccessManager` is asynchronous, so it needs an event loop to do any downloading. But when the function `on_pushButton_clicked()` returns and gives the control back to the event loop, the `QNetworkAccessManager` is already destroyed, and didn't have the time to do anything.

When you add a `QMessageBox` in `DownloadManager::execute`, you are in fact running another event loop withing the slot `on_pushButton_clicked()`, and it gives the opportunity to the `QNetworkAccessManager` to do its work.

The correct solution would be to allocate `DownloadManager` dynamically, and eventually to make it destroy itself when it has finished all downloads.

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    DownloadManager *manager = new DownloadManager(this);    
    manager->execute();
}

void DownloadManager::downloadFinished(QNetworkReply *reply)
{
    ...
    if (currentDownloads.isEmpty())
        this->deleteLater();
}
```